# Prove that $\frac{x^x}{x+y}+\frac{y^y}{y+z}+\frac{z^z}{z+x} \geqslant \frac32$

Tags: inequality

> $x,y,z >0$, prove
>   $$\frac{x^x}{x+y}+\frac{y^y}{y+z}+\frac{z^z}{z+x} \geqslant \frac32$$

I have a solution for this beautiful and elegant inequality. I am posting this inequality to share and see other solutions from everyone on MSE.

---

Since some of you asked for my solution, I used the following estimations
$$x^x \geqslant \frac12 \left(x^2+1 \right)$$

Proving rest of this inequality is very simple.

*Method 1:*
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{x^x}{x+y} \geqslant \frac12\sum_{cyc}\frac{x^2+1}{x+y}\geqslant \frac12 \left( \frac{(x+y+z)^2}{2(x+y+z)}+\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{x+y} \right) \geqslant \frac12 \sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{x+y}{4}+\frac{1}{x+y} \right) \geqslant \frac12 \sum_{cyc} 2 \cdot\sqrt{\frac{x+y}{4}\cdot \frac{1}{x+y}} \geqslant \frac32$$

*Method 2:*
$$\sum_{cyc} \frac{x^x}{x+y} \geqslant \frac12 \sum_{cyc}\frac{x^2+1}{x+y} \geqslant \frac32 \sqrt[3]{\frac{(x^2+1)(y^2+1)(z^2+1)}{(x+y)(y+z)(z+x)}}\geqslant \frac32$$
It is because C-S yields $$(x^2+1)(y^2+1) \geqslant (x+y)^2$$
so $$\frac{(x^2+1)(y^2+1)(z^2+1)}{(x+y)(y+z)(z+x)} \geqslant 1$$

*Method 3:*

Notice that
$$\sum_{cyc} \frac{x^2+1}{x+y}=\sum_{cyc} \frac{y^2+1}{x+y}$$
Hence
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{x^x}{x+y} \geqslant \frac12 \sum_{cyc}\frac{x^2+1}{x+y}=\frac14\sum_{cyc} \frac{x^2+y^2+2}{x+y} \geqslant\frac14\sum_{cyc}\frac{\frac{(x+y)^2}{2}+2}{x+y}$$$$=\frac14 \sum_{cyc} \left(\frac{x+y}{2}+\frac{2}{x+y} \right) \geqslant \frac14 \sum_{cyc}2 =\frac32$$

Can you find a different solution that does not employ the estimation $x^x \geqslant \frac12(x^2+1)$ ?

---

***Update 1***

The solution of **user260822** is not correct. This is not a Nesbitt's inequality. 
We have
$$\frac{x}{x+y}+\frac{y}{y+z}+\frac{z}{z+x} > 1 $$
(not $\frac32$)

---

***Update 2***

Another similar question I posted a few weeks back

[Unconventional Inequality $ \frac{x^x}{|x-y|}+\frac{y^y}{|y-z|}+\frac{z^z}{|z-x|} > \frac72$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1777632/unconventional-inequality-fracxxx-y-fracyyy-z-fraczzz-x)

Please help. Thank you

Comment: It's not really what Math.SE is for. If you have a solution already and want to know what other solutions are possible, then post your own solution in the question.

Comment: @YuriyS Why ? i like his idea, it is a lot better than posting direct solution.

Comment: please post your solution so that we can see it

Comment: wow, I did not know about that reduction for x^x .

Comment: @ritwiksinha: Math SE is **not** a contest ground. The proper way would be for him/her to post the question as well as answer his/her own question with his/her solution.

Comment: @novice: That is actually a very weak inequality, equivalent to $(1+x)^{1+x} \ge 1+x+\frac12 x^2$. A far stronger inequality is $(1+x)^{1+x} \ge 1+x+x^2+\frac12 x^3$. Both can be obtained by asymptotic expansion or differentiation.

Comment: @user21820 Weaker as in - it doesnt always hold?

Comment: @novice: Weaker just means that it is a lower-order approximation at the equality. In particular, the error is $Θ(x^2)$ whereas the error for my inequality is $Θ(x^4)$. Both of these are, of course, as $x \to 0$.

Comment: @user21820 : Still don't get it. let me google it.

Comment: @novice: Google for "Landau notation"; the error is simply the difference between the original expression and the approximation. In the inequality mentioned in the question, the lower bound deviates from $(1+x)^{1+x}$ by $Θ(x^2)$ as $x \to 0$, whereas my lower bound deviates from $(1+x)^{1+x}$ by only $Θ(x^4)$ as $x \to 0$.

Comment: @user21820 : Thanks a ton!

Comment: I think it's the best way for this question!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since $e^x\geq 1+x$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$, by letting $x=-\log u$ we have that for any $u >0$, $\log u\geq 1-\frac{1}{u}$, and so $u\log u>u-1$ for any $u>0$. Combining these two inequalities, it follows that $$\sqrt{x^x y^y}= \exp\left(\frac{x\log x}{2}+\frac{y\log y}{2}\right)\geq \exp\left(\frac{x+y}{2}-1\right)\geq   \frac{x+y}{2}.$$ Hence $$\frac{x^x}{x+y}+\frac{y^y}{y+z}+\frac{z^z}{z+x}\geq \frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{\frac{x^x}{y^y}}+\sqrt{\frac{y^y}{z^z}}+\sqrt{\frac{z^z}{x^x}}\right),$$ and the result follows from the [AM-GM inequality.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means)

---

**Remark:** By combining $e^x\geq 1+x$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $u\log u\geq u-1$ for $u>0$ as above, we obtain the following "reverse exponential AM-GM inequality": $$\sqrt[n]{x_{1}^{x_{1}}x_{2}^{x_{2}}\cdots x_{n}^{x_{n}}}\geq \frac{x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n}{n}.$$

Answer (score 3):

Preliminary note: If $x=1+u$ and $y=1+v$ with some small $u,v$ then 
$$
\frac{x^x}{x+y} = \frac{(1+u)^{1+u}}{2+u+v} \approx \frac12 \frac{1+u}{1+\frac12u+\frac12v} \approx \frac12\left(1+\frac12u-\frac12v\right)
= \frac12 + \frac{x-y}4.
$$

---

We will prove that 
$$
\frac{x^x}{x+y} \ge \frac12 + \frac{x-y}{4}.  \tag1
$$
Then the statement follows immediately.

(1) is equivalent with
$$
x^x \ge \frac{x+y}2 + \frac{x^2-y^2}4 = \frac{(x+1)^2}4 - \frac{(y-1)^2}4.
$$
The maximum of the RHS is attained at $y=1$, so it suffices to prove
$$
x^x \ge \frac{(x+1)^2}4,
$$
or equivalently,
$$
f(x) = x \ln x - \ln4 -2\ln(x+1)\ge0.
$$

We have $f'(x) = 1+\ln x - \frac{2}{x+1}>0$ for $x>1$ and
$f'(x)<0$ for $0<x<1$.
Therefore, $\min f = f(1)=0$ and $f(x)\ge0$ for all $x>0$.
Equality occurs in (1) only for $x=y=1$.